# Find all links in a html file and store it in an array

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium. I want to save all the links (that are partial links ("https://instagram.com/p/")) in an array from a html page.

My code looks like this:

```
src = browser.page_source
#here I get the html page
tag = src.findall("https://instagram.com/p/")  
tag = []
print(tag)
```

I want to do something just like this but don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://instagram.com/p/")

a_tag = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
links = [tag.get_attribute('href') for tag in a_tag]

print(links)
```

Comment: OP wants to `save all the links (those are partial links (e.g. "https://instagram.com/p/"))` within an array. You are invoking `get()` for the sample _url_